# Mysql ignore contition 'where' on varchar primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `slug`;
CREATE TABLE `slug` (
  `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `table` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`slug`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_table` (`id`,`table`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `slug` (`slug`, `id`, `table`) VALUES
('aaa', 3,  'team');
```

I have select

```
SELECT `slug`, `id`, `table` 
FROM `slug` 
WHERE (`slug` = 0)
```

and result is

```
+------+----+-------+
| slug | id | table |
+------+----+-------+
| aaa  |  3 | team  |
+------+----+-------+
```

Condition is *slug = 0*, but I get row where slug is 'aaa'.

Any idea?

Mysql version 5.5.38-0ubuntu0.12.04.1

Comment: I don't know why it's not returning an error...but there should be some implicit conversion issues happening here.  slug is defined as a varchar, slug = 0 is comparing it to an integer.   Try slug = '0'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a note, it is a bad idea to use reserved words, such as `table` as column names.  This however is irrelevant to your question.

The important part of the query is:

```
WHERE slug = 0
```

How does MySQL handle this?  What can it do?  After all, you've declared `slug` to be a `varchar()` but it is being compared to an integer.  Well, what MySQL does is silent conversion to the numeric type.  So, it converts the value in `slug` to an integer.

Which integer?  If `slug` were `'123'`, then it would be easy.  The value would be `123`.  Instead, the value is `aaa`.  MySQL's conversion rules are to convert the leading "digits" of the string to a number, until are no more "digits".  When there are no digits at all, the value is `0`.  I've put digits in quotes because it includes '-', '.', and 'e' (for exponential notation).

So, your `where` clause is comparing any string that doesn't start with a numeric `0` to `0`.  The following values should all pass:  `'aaa'`, `'zzz'`, `'0abc'`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. 
In MySQL, a zero number can be equal to any string.
So when you want to compare a string with a value of an integer column, you have to cast your integer value into a string.